# warning and fatal error in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, warnings

This is what the error is:

> Warning: include(/home3/travcure/public_html/pages/class.utils.inc.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home3/travcure/public_html/index.php on line 113
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home3/travcure/public_html/pages/class.utils.inc.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php.;pages/;/home3/travcure/public_html\pages') in /home3/travcure/public_html/index.php on line 113
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined function eiTxuqFQGsvY() in /home3/travcure/public_html/index.php on line 113

I can't find the pages folder.

This is happening because I accidentally deleted index.php which was in the WordPress root folder and put another index.php file from my other site. I guess root index.php is same in all versions.

Comment: you can see it in the bottom of my website. here https://indianmedtrip.com/

Comment: Try to upload new fresh `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` folders.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , would it affect my site, I mean can anything bad happen?

Comment: No, download fresh WordPress and replace those folders, its secure.

Comment: Thank you I will do that n get back to you.

Comment: Hey I tried it in localhost Im getting this error
 Class 'WP_Widget' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\www\indianmedtrip\wp-includes\widgets\class-wp-widget-pages.php on line 17

Comment: it seems you have issue with your theme or one of the plugins.

Comment: replacing wp-settings.php worked I hope nothing will happen to my database

Comment: No it will not cause any problem to your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to give you exact solution, because your problem maybe caused by many reasons. Though below you can find some of the useful points.

- Download fresh WordPress, replace `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` folders.
- Try to change theme, maybe theme caused issues.
- Try to rename plugin one by one, sometimes plugin can harm your website.
- Also replace core files in root folder (ie: **wp-settings.php**)

Comment: then no someone need to look it personally. cant help like this.

Comment: had some code at the bottom of my root index.php file, Removed it and it worked. By the way thanks bcuz somehow I upgraded my wordpress to 4.4.2

Comment: Great :) its always best practice to use latest WP.